# How to use mid-level fine tuning in Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, vgg-net

My task is to adapt a pre-trained network from Keras for classification of aerial images (we have a database of 30 categories of aerial images, each containing 200-400 images). 
Now, what I don't really understand is this next part.

We must use mid-level fine tuning using a smaller image database, which contains 21 aerial categories.

How can I achieve this?

Should I try to fine tune the smaller database on top of a VGG16 network and then save the model and train the larger database on top of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that they want you to fine-tune a trained model by freezing its first X layers and only updating the weights of the last few layers (maybe just the last one, not sure what "mid-level fine-tuning" means).

You need to take your trained model and replace its last layer with 30 outputs to a new layer of 21 outputs. Then you need to freeze all your other layers (except the new one) and train the model on the new dataset.

In Keras you just need to set: "trainable=False" for each layer.
[How can I "freeze" Keras layers?](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-freeze-keras-layers)